# iTunes File Sharing Clarification

Tags: ios, file-sharing

I recently had my application rejected, by Apple for:

> "Your app has the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key set to true in the `Info.plist`, but files and folders not intended for file-sharing are contained within its Documents folder..."

I am storing my application data in the documents directory, images and the core data database.  This is a very simple progress, that allows the user to backup and import data.  Below are the major steps:

1. The user can backup the data, which zips the folder.
2. The user can then use iTunes file sharing to take out the backup.
3. The user can import, the zip file which overwrites the data in the documents directory.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues?  It seems like I am using this correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the zip file in the `Documents` folder, not any other files. The fact that you also put your core-data files (and some of the other files the user shouldn't see) in the `Documents` folder is why it was rejected.

You can store any files that the user shouldn't see in another folder such as the `Application Support` folder.

Comment: Any recommendation for where you would put the core data database, and other images at?

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: I really wanted the data to be backed up in iCloud, that folder will in the documents directory.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything in the `Application Support` folder is backed up to iCloud. I know it is with an iTunes backup.

Comment: I moved all my data in the Application Support file, and my application was still rejected for the exact same reason.

Comment: Are you sure you submitted the updated app? When you run the updated app and you look at your app's Documents directory in iTunes, what files do you see? Do you still see files that the user shouldn't see?

Comment: Yes, only the backup files are there, the reviewers keep saying they don't see any files in there, but they are not hitting the backup button to create a backup, it's driving me crazy!